# Strange underfull hbox?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm not sure if I found a bug or I'm just missing an argument somewhere, but I get an underfull hbox with the following code, and I have no idea where it's coming from:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}[h]{c c}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      xlabel = $q$,
      ylabel = $d$,
      xtick={-6,-4,...,7},ytick={.05,.1,...,.3},
      height=7cm, width=7cm,
      axis lines*=left,
      xmin = -6, xmax = 6,
      ymin = 0, ymax = .25,
      every y tick label/.append style  =
        { 
          /pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 2, 
           fixed zerofill,
           fixed
        },/pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      xlabel =$q$,
      ylabel =$p$,
      xtick={-6,-4,...,7},ytick={.1,.2,...,1},
      height=7cm, width=7cm,
      axis lines*=left,
      xmin = -6, xmax = 6,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 1,
      every y tick label/.append style  =
        { 
          /pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 2, 
           fixed zerofill,
           fixed
        },/pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}}
\caption{stuff}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get any underfull box warnings with your example code.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina What version of `minted` are you running ?

Comment: I get the warning, which is clearly due to loading `minted` after `hyperref`. Switch the position of the packages.

Comment: @1010011010 `Package: minted 2010/03/16 v1.7`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get just an `Underfull \hbox` warning, but also

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same iden
tifier (name{figure.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv
```

This is clearly due to `minted` doing things to `\caption` that aren't caught by `hyperref`, since it has already been loaded.

Just change the package loading order.

By the way, I don't understand the complication of `tabular` inside `\resizebox`. Note also that there is no `h` option for `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      xlabel = $q$,
      ylabel = $d$,
      xtick={-6,-4,...,7},ytick={.05,.1,...,.3},
      height=.45\textwidth, width=.45\textwidth,
      axis lines*=left,
      xmin = -6, xmax = 6,
      ymin = 0, ymax = .25,
      every y tick label/.append style  =
        { 
          /pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 2, 
           fixed zerofill,
           fixed
        },/pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      xlabel =$q$,
      ylabel =$p$,
      xtick={-6,-4,...,7},ytick={.1,.2,...,1},
      height=.45\textwidth, width=.45\textwidth,
      axis lines*=left,
      xmin = -6, xmax = 6,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 1,
      every y tick label/.append style  =
        { 
          /pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 2, 
           fixed zerofill,
           fixed
        },/pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{stuff}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not get that warning.

Comment: @1010011010 Look in the `.log` file